# Sections and pages

Tags: sectioning

Can someone show me how to avoid this?
[image]

Like i want to make a space between the title of the section and pages.

Comment: Could you provide a MWE?

Comment: You can change the font size for the header or/and change the horizontal margins for your document.

Comment: You should avoid long parts (or chapter or section or so...) naming. If you absolutely cannot keep it short/concise enough, consider adding a short version of it, using `\section[short version]{long version}`. For instance: `\section[Algebraic stuffs]{Tensor, symmetric algebras and the universal envelopping algebra}`.

Comment: The other option is to increase \headheight and put the header into a \parbox.

Answer (score 3):

You could, of course, just change the size.  But other than that, you have two options, as I see it:

1.) You could use the optional argument for `\section`, which allows you to enter a different string which will be used in headers and in the TOC:

```
\section[Tensor, Symmetric, and Universal 
    Algebras]{Tensor, Symmetric Algebras,
    and the Universal Enveloping Algebras}
```

That will do what you want.

2.)  Automatically truncate the string with another package.  Donald Arsenau's `truncate` package is (in my opinion) the best for this.  Use `fancyhdr` to design your own page style, which will include the `\truncate` for your section mark; that will shorten the string.  Something like this (faked up to demonstrate; not a serious pagestyle definition):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{truncate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \fancyhead{}\fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\truncate{3in}\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{6}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\section{Tensor, Symmetric Algebras, and the Universal Enveloping Algebras}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

That will yield:

[image: Results]

I hope one or the other of these can solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much